# Linq to SQL: How to save the final queries to a log file?

Tags: linq, entity-framework, linq-to-sql, logging

I am looking after an application with lots of LINQ to SQL queries. This is basically SilverLight application with MVC. Some of the data loading is taking quite a bit of time. I wanted to know the exact query that is fired on SQL server. Is there any way of storing the generated T-SQL statements to some kind of a log file?

Please suggest some other possible ways as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

LINQ to SQL datacontexts have a property [`Log`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.log.aspx) that holds a reference to a `TextWriter` where the text of all the generated SQL queries is written to. You could for example open a `StreamWriter` for a disk file, then assign it to the Log property of your datacontext. See here for some nice examples: http://damieng.com/blog/2008/07/30/linq-to-sql-log-to-debug-window-file-memory-or-multiple-writers

Comment: Sorry, I am naive on LINQ and could not locate the log property. We use MVC and I could not see the log property.

Comment: "Log" is a property of the DataContext class. See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.log.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to use the SQL Server Profiler. This will log all queries to a trace file that you can load up after tracing to see how long queries took etc.

Check out this intro.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650699.aspx

Make sure you select the correct event such as Statement Completed.

See this post for further reference

http://weblogs.asp.net/zeeshanhirani/archive/2008/04/18/how-to-use-profiler-with-linq-to-sql-queries.aspx

Comment: +1 even though the OP askes for a log, SQL Server profiler is indeed also a good solution and there is no coding involved

Comment: Yes, that is true. I am now exploring the SQL Server Profiler. Thanks a lot. With coding, I can be very specific to log specific queries. In case of the SQL Server Profiler, it works on event and tend to log everything. Might be I shall have to learn on filtering etc.

Comment: @Kangkan - I usually use sql server profiler together with the debugger. I put a breakboint just before what I want to trace, switch on the profile, step over the part i want traced and switch it of again. Since I am using sql server express i use the AnjLab profiler and not the one from MS